# difference between these two mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I thought these two queries were the same. But the results turned out the first query's constraints starting with the four ANDs worked, many wrong rows with the left join are returned. The results in the second query look like right.
Could anyone explain what's the difference between these two queries?
this question is similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782339/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-queries), but I 100% sure that the results are different.

```
       SELECT uinfo.serial_number, uinfo.firmware, upd.objtype, upd.category
       FROM UnitInfo uinfo
       LEFT JOIN 
       UnitUpdateInfo upd
       ON uinfo.serial_number = upd.serial_number
       AND substring(uinfo.serial_number,1,2) NOT IN ('AB','CD','EF','GH')  
       AND substring(uinfo.serial_number,1,1) NOT LIKE 'M%'
       AND upd.objtype ='HEEN' 
       AND TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uinfo.firmware, '-', -2), '-', 1)) LIKE '3.0%'   


       SELECT uinfo.serial_number, uinfo.firmware, upd.objtype, upd.category
       FROM UnitInfo uinfo
       LEFT JOIN 
       UnitUpdateInfo upd
       ON uinfo.serial_number = upd.serial_number
       WHERE substring(uinfo.serial_number,1,2) NOT IN ('AB','CD','EF','GH')  
       AND substring(uinfo.serial_number,1,1) NOT LIKE 'M%'
       AND upd.objtype ='HEEN' 
       AND TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uinfo.firmware, '-', -2), '-', 1)) LIKE '3.0%'
```

[edit]
the second query is the same as:

```
       SELECT uinfo.serial_number, uinfo.firmware, upd.objtype, upd.category
       FROM UnitInfo uinfo
       INNER JOIN 
       UnitUpdateInfo upd
       ON uinfo.serial_number = upd.serial_number
       WHERE substring(uinfo.serial_number,1,2) NOT IN ('AB','CD','EF','GH')  
       AND substring(uinfo.serial_number,1,1) NOT LIKE 'M%'
       AND upd.objtype ='HEEN' 
       AND TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uinfo.firmware, '-', -2), '-', 1)) LIKE '3.0%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as a right-hand side table in a `LEFT JOIN` has fields compared for e.g. equality in the `WHERE` clause, it effectively becomes an `INNER JOIN` - in your query, you're forcing the `objtype` field of `UnitUpdateInfo` to be non-NULL => the join must have succeeded.

The first query, with all the join logic as part of the `LEFT JOIN` will include all rows from the first table joined to those rows from the second table - with NULLs for the second tables fields where a join wasn't possible.

The second query will *not* include those rows from the first table that don't join to the second.

Comment: I'm still confused. you mean the 2nd query is a inner join because I have some where condition to the table upd, right? That makes sense. But why the condition like "AND upd.objtype ='HEEN'" in the 1st query doesn't work?

Comment: The conditions you have for the `LEFT JOIN` in the first query specify when rows from the right-hand side table of the join will be matched to the rows in the left-hand side table.  It's the case that this condition is 'working' - just not as you're wanting.

Comment: for 1st query, upd.objtype='HEEN' doesn't work for sure, because lots of rows with NULL objtype are included in the result set. I'm afraid I didn't get your point clearly. In short, if my purpose is to get all rows in uinfo, upd which satisfies the three conditions for uinfo and then one condition for upd, what's the correct query?

Comment: Your second query looks like the correct one given your specification - but with the LEFT JOIN replaced by an INNER JOIN.

Comment: great, confirmed about this. For 2nd query, with all the where conditions I have, the left join result is the same as inner join. For the 1st query, if change join as inner join, the result is the same as 2nd one, but for left join, the result set is much bigger. All these more rows are from NULL rows from uinfo with impossible join with upd, which makes those where conditions not working.